# Ion-range color split

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I would like to know why my `ion-range` has color split between "steps":

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

The code looks like this at the moment:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-range class="IonRange" (ionChange)="cambioDineroyPageviews(Valor)" [(ngModel)]="Valor" min="1" max="5" snaps="true"></ion-range>
</ion-item>
```

I have the following CSS for this ion-range

```
.IonRange{
  --bar-background: #A5F3EB;
  --bar-background-active: #FF0000;
  --bar-height: 15%;
  --knob-background: #999999;
}
```

Comment: can you share expected output

i think you have use ` --bar-background` and `--bar-background-active` color

and also what is the value of `Valor` ??

Comment: Could you please try to reproduce the issue in **[this Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66308891?file=src/app/pages/home/home.page.ts)**? I used the same styles but it seems to be working properly there. So there must be some other styles affecting the `ion-range`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the help, solution was to change "snaps" to false